# Memory leaking and strange heap allocation profiling

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, memory-leaks

I have made a simple slideshow script, and I have noticed that memory after some time starts to leaks. It is really simple script so, there should not be memory leaks.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
var current_index = 0;
var max_index = 5;

function delaySlide() {

    $("#slider").find("[data-index='" + current_index + "']").toggleClass("transparent");
  current_index++;

    if( current_index >= max_index )
    current_index = 0;

     $("#slider").find("[data-index='" + current_index + "']").toggleClass("transparent");
}

window.setInterval(function(){delaySlide(); }, 1000 );
</script>
```

When I fire Chrome's Task Manager (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), and turn on JavaScript memory tab (right click on list's header), I can see that memory used by JS is constantly increasing. Of course after some time, GC fires up, cleans up some memory, but not *all* memory. After several hours I can see that there is some memory loss.

So I started to record memory allocation timeline from within the chrome to see where the memory goes. Everything look perfect! Memory is allocated, then freed as soon as it is not needed anymore.

What really puzzles me is that when I started to record allocations, when I checked Chrome's Task Manager I was surprised that memory isn't increasing anymore.

As soon as I stop recording heap profile, JavaScript memory (and overall all memory) starts to increase again.

So, what's happening here at all? Do I, or don't have a memory leaks? Why is that strange chrome behavior?

Comment: As long as it does not crash somewhen (out of memory) everything is fine.

Comment: Why `function(){delaySlide(); }` instead of `delaySlide` ?

Comment: @JonasW. actually it is crashing, after day or so usage in embedded environment.